# Ubuntu doesn't use inactive memory and does swapping. Why?

Tags: memory, ubuntu-16.04, swap

What do I have:
1. Ubuntu 16.4 (VPS).
2. Free memory:

## free -m

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2048         916           0         251     1131         930
Swap:           512         183         328
```

ZERO, but available 930. What is that?

Lets check meminfo.

## cat /proc/meminfo

```
MemTotal:        2097152 kB
MemFree:               0 kB
Cached:          1092204 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Active:           926032 kB
Inactive:        1003456 kB
Active(anon):     358948 kB
Inactive(anon):   478336 kB
Active(file):     567084 kB
Inactive(file):   525120 kB
Unevictable:        4440 kB
Mlocked:           16716 kB
SwapTotal:        524288 kB
SwapFree:         337304 kB
Dirty:              3664 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        837284 kB
Shmem:            257492 kB
Slab:              69176 kB
SReclaimable:      51680 kB
SUnreclaim:        17496 kB
```

We can look here on inactive memory. That is it. Ubuntu uses PageCache mechanism to store in memory pages from disk. It loads data from disk, keeping it in memory and when it needs just give it from memory. Active means frequently, inactive means once loaded and can be freed when it needs and used for other reason. Before freed if it has changes than this changes should be stored in disk. Sounds very good, it should be very fast!

3. What data do we have in this memory?

I have a web site with a lot of images, search bots always searching something and opening a lot of pages. So, I assume that this is a mostly images that cached in memory. Lets check this with vmtouch:

## vmtouch uploads/

```
           Files: 947554
     Directories: 452
  Resident Pages: 336841/7859937  1G/29G  4.29%
         Elapsed: 15.938 seconds
```

It looks like 1 GB cached! Ok. Everything is looking calculated right. Of course it is not only the images, but images can take this 1GB of disk space.

**The problem:**
I have installed monitoring collectd. And when I open swap information I see strange things.

[collectd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdnKB.png)

blue lines means swapping out. Swap out is when system takes Page and stores it on disk and then use freed memory for other work. But it should use inactive memory! It should free inactive memory and not do swapping out.

This blue lines every 5 minutes. Its time when cron for sphinx is running. The command is:

indexer --all --rotate

It does indexing for 3 indexes. Each runs query with MySQL. Tables has about 40.000 records to index and all these records splited on 3 indexes.

Usage of the memory is looking like that:

[memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7fPZ.png)

Sometimes system does freeing of memory. It looks like a green triangle space on image. It does a free than it start feeling with PageCache.

And I will show memory usage from ps command (part of output):

## ps aux --sort -rss

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
mysql    25736 48.9 18.9 2587348 396632 ?      Sl   Aug01 2130:22 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
sphinxs+   352  0.1  1.8 543592 39784 ?        Sl   May01 209:07 /usr/bin/searchd
www-data 11926  1.3  1.4 388392 29636 ?        S    15:28   0:02 php /var/www/html/ma-ideals.com/index.php -p fb -t 10
www-data 11322  0.1  0.7 449716 16568 ?        S    15:06   0:02 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 11761  0.2  0.7 449716 15812 ?        S    15:21   0:01 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 11535  0.1  0.7 449716 15432 ?        S    15:12   0:01 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 11338  0.1  0.7 449712 15320 ?        S    15:07   0:02 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 11478  0.1  0.6 447664 14548 ?        S    15:10   0:02 php-fpm: pool www
```

Can somebody help me to research deeper what is going on behind this swapping out and why ubuntu is not using inactive memory in this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with a little swapout?  If the kernel can find really cold pages, why would you want them wasting memory?

There seems to be a lot of superstition about swap - people who religiously believe systems are better without it, etc.  The fact is that swap is just optimization of your memory use.  Swapout is *good* for a system, since it makes physical memory available for more important uses.  OTOH, if you see nontrivial swapIN, then you might have a problem (but that's not inherent to having swap or in experiencing modest swapout.)

Comment: No problem about little swap out. But when there is 1GB of inactive memory why ubuntu did a swap? It is faster just to use an inactive memory than swap out. Isn't it? when it swapping, it saving data in disk to swap in the future. But it can take inactive memory with no this disk operations. May be I am wrong but that is how I understand this.

Comment: Is there any cost to moderate swap-out? Not really. Obviously, all disk systems are DMA and have been for decades, so there's basically no CPU overhead. There's nothing waiting on the SO to complete either (especially since disk writes are posted.) A swapped-out page may never be swapped back in...

Think of swapped-out pages as really-really-inactive memory. Just another layer on the continuum of activity. Your system will use inactive memory, and SO just lets the system use more inactive memory.